# Lifetime extension on subobject of return value?

Tags: c++, c++20

Please consider the following C++20 program:

```
struct S {
  S(int x) : x(x) {}

  int x;
};

S f() { return S(42); }

int main() {
    auto&& r = f().x;
    return r;
}
```

Is this undefined behaviour and the reference dangles? or is the int object lifetime extended?

Comment: _"...Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a __subobject__ thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary  My reading is the life-time of the temporary `S` ( returned from `F()` ) is extended.

Comment: @RichardCritten: It looks like it works in recent versions of gcc and clang, but not in msvc.  See comment in linked question.